# Classification: Layer error: Classifier training failed: 'Only one class.'

Tags: google-earth-engine

i am new in GEE and try a tutorial from this https://www.gears-lab.com/intro_rs_lab4/ but the result show error classifier training failed: 'Only one class.'. So i try to fix it and combine with this tutorial https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/classification but again the result show error training failed: 'Only one class

this is my code https://code.earthengine.google.com/5412d64d8ba217f879be98f6ba491146
im stuck.

sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train(training, 'landcover', bands);
```

You're telling the classifier to learn to classify points according to the value of the 'landcover' property. But in all of your input data, the value of `landcover` is always `0`, so there is only one class, `0`. This is reported as an error because a classification with one class is not useful — it gives no information.

To fix this, in the geometry list, click on the gear icon for each of your point sets:

[image: Geometry Imports list]

Then in the "Configure geometry imports" dialog, give each one a **different number** for the `landcover` property. I edited them so that `urban` is 0, `forest` is 1, `agriculture` is 2, and `water` is 3.

[image: Property list in dialog]

After you do this, the script will run without error and your classifier will be trained successfully. Then you'll want to view the results. Here's how to do that with a palette set up to match your marker colors:

```
Map.addLayer(classified, {min: 0, max: 3, palette: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'cyan']});
```

[Here is your script with those two modifications (property value in the geometry imports, and `Map.addLayer` in use).](https://code.earthengine.google.com/41cf1dd6ef0b2704ff0fa432086fe7cd)

Comment: solved, thanks you sir.